# How to reverse an array from index i to index j multiple times using cartesian tree?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, cartesian-tree

Suppose I have a given array A. Now there are multiple operations of the form

```
reverse i,j // means reverse the array Ai..j inclusive
```

and

```
print i,j
```

Print the array Ai..j.

Example ,

```
A = 6 9 1 10 4 15 9
reverse 2,3
A = 6 1 9 10 4 15 9
reverse 3,6
A = 6 1 15 4 10 9 9
print 1,4

6 1 15 4
```

I have heard that it can be done by cartesian trees. So I have been reading the blog [here](http://www.infoarena.ro/treapuri)   But I still can't understand how we can do this using cartesian tree, what is the key and value should be and how we should implement ?

Comment: `swap(i, j);` `i++` `j--` repeat until `i < j`

Comment: I was hoping someone who already know cartesian tree would be able to answer this question and for this there is no need for the site. I provided the site so that people can know which implementation of the cartesian tree am I following.(And there is no english site with cartesian tree implementation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this problem, a treap(aka Cartesian tree) with implicit key should be used(there is no key at all, it is just about merging them in right order). The value of a node is an array element that it represents. To implement reverse operation, you can maintain reverse flag for each node(true if it must be reversed, false otherwise) and push it lazily(to push here means to exchange left and right children of a node and flip the value of a flag in its children).

Pseudo code for push:

```
void push(Node node)
    if node.flag
        swap(node.left, node.right)
        if node.left != null
            node.left.flag = not node.left.flag
        if node.right != null
            node.right.flag = not node.right.flag
```

Comment: can you explain with an example please ?? I don't understand the part pushing !

Comment: if I swap the nodes,, wouldnt the key changed ? I mean left subtree should be less than node, but when you are swapping it becomes greater.

Comment: @Unbound There is no key at all. There is nothing to change.

Comment: thanks , I was just having trouble to understand as to why , after merging the order would be the same as previous array.

Answer (score 0):

Follow in below some examples that you could use.

```js
console.log(
  Array.from({length:1}).reduce((acc,item)=>acc.reverse(),[1,2,3]),
  Array.from({length:2}).reduce((acc,item)=>acc.reverse(),[1,2,3]),
  Array.from({length:3}).reduce((acc,item)=>acc.reverse(),[1,2,3])
)

console.log(  Array.from({length:1}).reduce((acc,item)=>acc.reverse(),Array(...'love')).join(''),  Array.from({length:2}).reduce((acc,item)=>acc.reverse(),Array(...'love')).join(''),  Array.from({length:3}).reduce((acc,item)=>acc.reverse(),Array(...'love')).join('')
)

const reverseXTimes = (word, xTimes)=> Array.from({length:xTimes}).reduce((acc,item)=>acc.reverse(),Array(...word)).join('')

console.log(
  reverseXTimes('passion',1),
  reverseXTimes('passion',2),
  reverseXTimes('passion',3),
)
```